# What set of system-wide configuration settings can conflict when installing different applications on a unix-based OS?

Tags: configuration, development, deployment

Reading this [report on containerization](http://course.ece.cmu.edu/~ece845/docs/containers.pdf.) the authors mention that:

> A problem caused by Unix’s shared global filesystem is
>   the lack of configuration isolation. Multiple applications can
>   have conflicting requirements for system-wide configuration
>   settings.

I know that installing different applications for development, frequently different applications require different versions of the same libraries, or vaguely, that they require different system-wide configuration values. It is not clear to me what this set is on a unix-based OS.

What configuration values commonly cause this issue?

Naively, why is this not as much an issue once the application is deployed or installed by the end-user? Why is it that I cannot have the development build of similar applications running easily side by side, but I can download with a package manager and have them run with little or no problems?

Comment: It is unclear what problems you are having. Also there are no system-wide setting. Each applies to a process, and may be inherited by its children. If you tell us what problems you are having and what type of program you are developing, then we may be able to help with a solution.

Comment: Welcome to UNIX & Linux at Stack Exchange. As @ctrl-alt-delor mentioned, your question does not seem to be about a specific problem but more a general set of issues you state are frequently evident, but offer no examples. In fact, you are asking for examples of the problem. Maybe consider revising your question? It might help to check out the [tour] and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I was paraphrasing this IBM research report I was reading: http://course.ece.cmu.edu/~ece845/docs/containers.pdf. "A problem caused by Unix’s shared global filesystem is the lack of configuration isolation. Multiple applications can have conflicting requirements for system-wide configuration
settings." The question isn't about a problem I am having, but asking for an explanation of what these configuration values are.

Comment: @AOrona thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes while some things can be configured on an individual basis with environment variables. If a program has hard coded locations for files, then there can be a conflict.

A solution to this is namespaces. There are various types of namespace file-system, process, user, network, ...

In the case you refer to (file-system), a name space can present a completely different view of the file-system to processes in a different name space. Typically a sub-directory with in the host, will become the root of the new name-space.

It help manage namespaces, cgroups, etc, we can use containerisation tools. They just manage these kernel services for us, but make it much easier.

Any process running in the container will see a system with (typically) just a few processes running on it. It will see a sub-set of the file-system. It will see its own configuration of the network. It will see a sub-set of the system resources (CPUs, memory, etc).

Comment: Thank you! Is there any reading you recommend to better understand containerization?

Comment: Depends where you are now. What is your current understanding of Gnu/Linux?

Comment: Well I've taken 2 OS classes and done a little C programming but I am pretty new to gnu/linux

Comment: C is not the best language to start on (though it is 100 times better than C++). You are currently in the deep-end. Get to grips with the basics: Command line, directories, files, text processing tools, shell, redirection, pipes, shell-jobs, scripts, file-permissions, mount-points, ... Then learn an easier language (python is often used for beginners, but Berkeley's snap is better for a first language), then maybe implement some system commands (ls, cat, mv, cp, grep, etc).

Comment: ya I'm not that new but thanks

Comment: Depends where you are now. What is your current understanding of Gnu/Linux? (you have given two contradictory responses.)